# Viewing Kaggle Facial Recognition Dataset in Python 3.5

Tags: image, python-3.x, csv, image-processing

I have the following code to do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from builtins import range, input
# Note: you may need to update your version of future
# sudo pip install -U future

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Google Drive\\Udemy\\LP_CNN in Python\\facial-expression-recognition')
os.getcwd()

def getData(balance_ones=True):
    # images are 48x48 = 2304 size vectors
    # N = 35887
    Y = []
    X = []
    first = True
    for line in open('fer2013.csv'):
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            row = line.split(',')
            Y.append(int(row[0]))
            X.append([int((p)) for p in row[1].split()])

    X, Y = np.array(X) / 255.0, np.array(Y)

    if balance_ones:
        # balance the 1 class
        X0, Y0 = X[Y!=1, :], Y[Y!=1]
        X1 = X[Y==1, :]
        X1 = np.repeat(X1, 9, axis=0)
        X = np.vstack([X0, X1])
        Y = np.concatenate((Y0, [1]*len(X1)))

    return X, Y

label_map = ['Anger', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Surprise', 'Neutral']

def main():
    X, Y = getData(balance_ones=False)

    while True:
        for i in range(7):
            x, y = X[Y==i], Y[Y==i]
            N = len(y)
            j = np.random.choice(N)
            plt.imshow(x[j].reshape(48, 48), cmap='gray')
            plt.title(label_map[y[j]])
            plt.show()
        prompt = input('Quit? Enter Y:\n')
        if prompt == 'Y':
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This problem is that I got this code from a tutorial video that works with Python 2.7. When I run this on Python 3.5, I get the following errors:

```
runfile('C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition/show_images.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-efb5f5556496>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition/show_images.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition/show_images.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition/show_images.py", line 42, in main
    X, Y = getData(balance_ones=False)

  File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Udemy/LP_CNN in Python/facial-expression-recognition/show_images.py", line 24, in getData
    Y.append(int(row[0]))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
```

There are many threads online about fixing this problem with int and I have tried several things like int(float(row[0])) etc. but they are just leading to further errors :(

I would note that the dataset can be downloaded as a tar.gz file from Kaggle at https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/data

I appear to have downloaded it correctly as it displays well in both Excel (as a .csv) and in Notepad.

Does anybody know how to fix this please? Or have alternative Python 3.5 code for displaying images from a .csv file of pixels?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from builtins import range
# Note: you may need to update your version of future
# sudo pip install -U future

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def convert_tar2csv():
    df = pd.read_csv('fer2013.tar', compression='gzip',
                     header=0, sep=' ', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
    df.to_csv('fer2013.csv')

def getData(balance_ones=True, thresh=35889):
    # images are 48x48 = 2304 size vectors
    Y = []
    X = []
    cv = []
    first = True
    i = 0
    for line in open('fer2013.csv'):
        i += 1
        if first:
            first = False
        elif i < thresh:
            row = line.replace('"', '')[:-1].split(',')
            Y.append(int(row[0]))
            X.append([float(p) for p in row[1:-1]])
            cv.append(row[-1])

    X, Y, cv = np.array(X) / 255.0, np.array(Y), np.array(cv)

    if balance_ones:
        # balance the 1 class
        X0, Y0, cv0 = X[Y != 1, :], Y[Y != 1], cv[Y != 1]
        X1 = X[Y==1, :]
        X1 = np.repeat(X1, 9, axis=0)
        X = np.vstack([X0, X1])
        cv1 = cv[Y == 1, :]
        cv1 = np.repeat(cv1, 9, axis=0)
        cv = np.vstack([cv0, cv1])
        Y = np.concatenate((Y0, [1]*len(X1)))

    return X, Y, cv


def getBinaryData(thresh=35889):
    Y = []
    X = []
    cv = []
    i = 0
    first = True
    for line in open('fer2013.csv'):
        i += 1
        if first:
            first = False
        elif i < thresh:
            row = line.replace('"', '')[:-1].split(',')
            y = int(row[0])
            if y == 0 or y == 1:
                Y.append(y)
                X.append([float(p) for p in row[1:-1]])
                cv.append(row[-1])
    return np.array(X) / 255.0, np.array(Y), np.array(cv)


def getImageData():
    X, Y, cv = getData()
    N, D = X.shape
    d = int(np.sqrt(D))
    X = X.reshape(N, 1, d, d)
    return X, Y, cv
```

Good luck :)